# Chrome extension not loading content_scripts

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script, manifest.json

I am creating a chrome extension. Problem I am facing is I am able to see the html content but I am not seeing my js files included in content_scripts. I am checking this by inspecting on my extension & checking sources tab.
Mainfest -

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "My Plugin",
  "description": "some description",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
      {
          "matches": [
          "http://*/*",
          "https://*/*"
          ],
        "js": ["myPopup.js"]

      }
    ],

  "permissions": [
   "activeTab",
    "declarativeContent",
    "storage"
   ]
}
```

myPopup.js -

```
console.log("hello world")
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: DevTools has a separate panel for the content scripts where you can set breakpoints and debug it just like any other script: https://puu.sh/Eoh5O/33ebb785f3.png just don't forget to reload the extension and the web page when you edit the code.

Answer (score 0):

Source tab will display the scripts that are actually injected into page DOM.

If you are trying to debug the content script, then add a debugger to your content script. 
Open the developer tools and reload the page, you should be able to see content script in the source tab.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYscg.png)

Comment: DevTools has a separate panel for the content scripts where you can set breakpoints and debug it just like any other script: https://puu.sh/Eoh5O/33ebb785f3.png just don't forget to reload the extension and the web page when you edit the code.